# Distinct With Conditions in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, distinct, conditional-statements

Having a table such as this (only an example):

```
Program category status 
A         cat1    active
B         cat2    inactive
C         cat3    active
D         cat2    active
```

I would like to get distinct categories but only if the status is active if I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM table WHERE status='active'
```

it will not include cat2 as a distict value even though it appeared once as active. I would like all distinct categories returned even if it appears just once as active.

I could use a php loop to do this but I would rather not return every category being this is a large table.

Thank you in advance for any help.
First time posting but StackOverFlow has helped me many many times.

---

The actual table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE cats (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    programname varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    sub0 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    sub1 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    sub2 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    sub3 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    sub4 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    category varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    status varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARYKEY (id)
) ENGINE= InnoDBDEFAULT CHARSET= latin1;
```

Comment: what is the problem you are encountering? what will be your desired result?

Comment: I would like to return distinct categories and programnames if the status is active. Its for an ecommerce site and some categories I dont want shown unless they are logged in because of age. Because some stores sell adult and non adult merchandise but using distinct if one category has been flagged the entire program is disallowed even though the other categories in that program are safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still cannot reproduce the problem.
The output of the following example is

```
Books>Art>Modern
Books>Art>Concrete
Books>Art>Classicism
Books>Art>Naive
```

There are two records having `category=Books>Art>Classicism`. The first has `status=0` and is excluded by the WHERE clause while the second has `status=1`.
You can check that there are no typos in my example data by setting the `status` of the first record from `0` to `1` and you will see that `Books>Art>Classicism` is still only displayed once but right after `Books>Art>Modern` as the second record.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM soFoo WHERE status='1'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach( $stmt as $row ) {
    echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec("
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            programname varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            sub0 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            sub1 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            sub2 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            sub3 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            sub4 varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            category varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            status varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        ) ENGINE= InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET= latin1;
    ");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        INSERT INTO
            soFoo
            (
                programname, sub0, sub1, sub2,
                sub3, sub4,
                category, status
            )
        VALUES
            (
                :programname, :sub0, :sub1, :sub2,
                :sub3, :sub4,
                :category, :status
            )
    ');
    $data = array();
    $data[] = array(
        'programname'=>'BOOK Store',
        'sub0'=>'Books', 'sub1'=>'Art Books','sub2'=>'Modern Art',
        'sub3'=>null, 'sub4'=>null,
        'category'=>'Books>Art>Modern', 'status'=>'1'
    );
    // this one has category='Books>Art>Classicism' and status=0
    // the second but last element is a copy of this one with status=1
    $data[] = array(
        'programname'=>'BOOK Store',
        'sub0'=>'Books', 'sub1'=>'Art Books','sub2'=>'Modern Art',
        'sub3'=>null, 'sub4'=>null,
        'category'=>'Books>Art>Classicism', 'status'=>'0'
    );
    $data[] = array(
        'programname'=>'BOOK Store',
        'sub0'=>'Books', 'sub1'=>'Art Books','sub2'=>'Modern Art',
        'sub3'=>null, 'sub4'=>null,
        'category'=>'Books>Art>Modern', 'status'=>'1'
    );
    $data[] = array(
        'programname'=>'BOOK Store',
        'sub0'=>'Books', 'sub1'=>'Art Books','sub2'=>'Modern Art',
        'sub3'=>null, 'sub4'=>null,
        'category'=>'Books>Art>Concrete', 'status'=>'1'
    );
    $data[] = array(
        'programname'=>'BOOK Store',
        'sub0'=>'Books', 'sub1'=>'Art Books','sub2'=>'Modern Art',
        'sub3'=>null, 'sub4'=>null,
        'category'=>'Books>Art>Classicism', 'status'=>'1'
    );
    $data[] = array(
        'programname'=>'BOOK Store',
        'sub0'=>'Books', 'sub1'=>'Art Books','sub2'=>'Modern Art',
        'sub3'=>null, 'sub4'=>null,
        'category'=>'Books>Art>Naive', 'status'=>'1'
    );

    foreach( $data as $rec ) {
        $stmt->execute($rec);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 VolkerK. @RobNHood, if you can comment this answer along the acceptance, then that's great. :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work like this:

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7ad8/1)

```
select distinct category
from demo
where status = 'active';

| CATEGORY |
------------
|     cat1 |
|     cat3 |
|     cat2 |
```

Unless you really have some other conditions to apply here, which you may need to let us know :)

Comment: thats what I have been using but if inactive appears just once as a status it will not return that program at all. Its like it performs the where clause before it filters the distict and I was wondering is their anyway to do the opposite

Comment: how did this differ from the original statement of the OP? the tableName?

Comment: @user2110318 In the sample data you have given, `inactive` appears for `category 2`, yet it is being returned, because it's `active` as per your last record. Apology, perhaps if you could show us the expected results (if differs from what I have above - looking at your comments..)

Comment: Sorry if it was misleading no category 2 is blocked entirely even though it appears once as active

Comment: My local test returns the same result as the "SQL DEMO" link from bonCodigo's answer, i.e. `cat2` is included in the result set given your example data.

Comment: Yes I saw that and I am using the same thing in code but for some reason it's not behaving the same :(

Comment: @user2110318 *no category 2 is blocked entirely even though it appears once as active*... that's what's hard for us to *decode* here.. If you have categories for `active, inactive` status, then when you filter then, it should show like the above. HOWEVER your comment: *but if inactive appears just once as a status it will not return that program at all*, it tells me **YOUR TABLE STRUCTURE IS DIFFERENT OR YOU HAVE OTHER CONDITIONS...**

Comment: Actual table structure is id programname cat0 cat 1 cat 2 cat3 cat4 status with SELECT cat0 from table WHERE status='active'

Comment: @user2110318 maybe you haven't explain your problem well. Try explaining more precisely. The query you posted on your query actually  returns distinct categoryname which are active.

Comment: I apologize if I didnt explain things right. It's almost 4 am here and I have been programming all day I'm sure you all know what thats like I appreciate the feedback though and the confirmation that I in fact was doing it right. Problem must be somewhere else in code. If not I will try the other examples and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the actual sql statement that creates the table and some statements that insert data into that table, something like `CREATE TABLE foo ( ... )` and `INSERT INTO foo (...) VALUES (...)`. You can get the table definition via `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` or use some frontend application that lets you export the structure+data as sql statements, e.g. http://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: CREATETABLE `cats` (
 `id` int(11)NOT NUL LAUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `programname` varchar( 100)NOTNULL DEFAULT'',
 `sub0` varchar( 300)DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sub1` varchar( 300)DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sub2` varchar( 300)DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sub3` varchar( 300)DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sub4` varchar( 300)DEFAULT NULL ,
 `category` varchar( 300)DEFAULT NULL ,
 `status` varchar( 1)DEFAULT NULL ,
 PRIMARYKEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE= InnoDBDEFAULT CHARSET= latin1;

Comment: Now this is **DIFFERENT** from what you have initially given! What is `sub0` to `sub6`? What data is inside? Please give us some sample data for your entire table, your full SQL SELECT statment as @VolkerK mentioned.

Comment: its basically the same Sub0 would be the Parent category and Sub1 to 4 are Subcategories category is basically a string for database lookup to perform searches and programname is the vendors name.

Comment: Heres an example programname='BOOK Store',sub0='Books',sub1='Art Books',sub2='Modern Art' 3 and 4 null category='Books>Art>Modern' status='active'

Comment: The structure you've posted doesn't fit the example data: `status varchar( 1)` vs `status='active'`

Comment: sorry status is boolean so its 0 or 1

Comment: And please provide more than one example record - enough data to run an example script against; data you've tested your script with beforehand to show the behaviour you've described.... Btw the table structure, its indices and the example record you've provided suggest that your database layout is ...suboptimal. Any chance to fix that?

Comment: not really the data is all extracted from xml files and dumped into the database and programnames vary in length as well as the number of subcategories for the products. Honestly I have no idea why its not returning all of the categories. All I know is if I have say 2 products in the Category books and 1 is blocked it removes the books category all together. The sql I am using is just what I gave and it coincides with the examples posted as well. The Problem must be going on elsewhere. I have traced it for several hours and I have not been able to locate it.

Comment: I wouldnt have posted it if it was something simple as I have always looked for my own solutions. I am a retired platform game programmer. I do appreciate your efforts in helping I am sorry I wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM 
(SELECT category FROM table WHERE status='active') as temp
```